# require() returning empty object with gulp angular browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower, browserify

I am having a problem where I am building my project using gulp which is running a browserify task (with debowerify) on my external libraries that I have downloaded using bower. One of the libraries - angular-gridster - has been updated to use the UMD pattern and now it is throwing an error where the reference to angular is an empty object.

This is how the angular-gridster.js file starts:

```
(function(root, factory) {

    'use strict';

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['angular'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = factory(require('angular'));
    } else {
        // Browser, nothing "exported". Only registered as a module with angular.
        factory(root.angular);
    }
}(this, function(angular) {

'use strict';

// This is throwing my error
return angular.module('gridster', [])
```

and where it is trying to call angular.module() it is throwing the error 'angular.module is not a function'. On debugging it I can see angular is just an empty object and hasn't been loaded right. I am not sure if this is an issue with the require() method or gulp or browserify or debowerify...

Here is my gulp task

```
gulp.task('dependencies', function() {
gulp.src(paths.dependencies)
    .pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true,
        transform: ['debowerify']
    }).on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(concat('3rdparty.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js'));
```

});

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to move your library to node_modules and try to require() it ? I had many problem using browserify with debowerify because dependencies of bower libraries were only looking into bower lib and bower doesn't have a tree like node_modules. It might look in the wrong folders at the wrong place. You should also provide use the directory structures of each libs your trying to import and package.json

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lot of other components installed through bower that depend on angular, so if I try and move it over to node modules I get a lot of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out a solution to this, which was just to call the require() function and then pass the now global variable angular to the factory() method.

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(['angular'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    require('angular');
    module.exports = factory(angular);
} else {
    // Browser, nothing "exported". Only registered as a module with angular.
    factory(root.angular);
}
```